# How can we skip excessive logs to write in log file

Tags: java, logging, memory-leaks, log4j2

Currently, I'm using log4j framework in java code for logging.

While working on a module, I come accross and Observe, due to excessive logs, file size is increaing and some time the system is stuck. Is there any mechanism in log4j which can help me to skip few logs for writing in log file.

For Example:

Threshold value :  1000  (1000 logs can write in 1 minutes.)
In, 1 minute there are around 1100 logs lines are written in log file. if it crossess the limit of threshold value (i.e 1000),send an alert mail that 100 logs are skipped.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnaJJ.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3c2A.png)

Comment: you must use rolling log files and specify file size

Comment: And different log files for different logs. Excessive trace logs to a corresponding log with short pattern.

Comment: Could you please take a look of https://i.stack.imgur.com/j3c2A.png  and https://i.stack.imgur.com/bnaJJ.png    .  My Problem will not resolve using rolling log files

Comment: @vedprakashkamma: Log4j 1.x reached end-of-life 7 years ago. It's successor Log4j2 offers a [BurstFilter](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/filters.html#BurstFilter) that does what you are looking for.